# Printing number of input character given

Tags: c

I was working on an exercise program from *The C Programming Language* by K&R. I want to print the length of the words in the input and I am printing the length with the character 'X'.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    int c,a[20];
    int j,k,i=0;
    int ch;
    int count,count1;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\b')
        {
            ++i;
            a[i] = count;
            k = i;
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        count1 = a[i];

        for(j = 0; j < count1; j++)
        {
            printf("x");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What's the question?

Comment: `count` should initialize to `0`. E.g `int count=0`, `c=='\b'` probably  `c=='\t'`

Comment: `++i; a[i]=count;` --> `a[i]=count;++i;` or `a[i++]=count;`

Comment: `count1=a[i];`. Since `i` starts at `0` in this loop, and since `a[0]` is uninitialised due to the `++i` before `a[i]=count;` my run spills out `x`s almost forever as the undefined `a[0]` might print none, or maybe billions of `x`.

Comment: regarding the line: 'void main ()'  there are only two valid (and one optional) ways to write the main function statement.  'int main( void )' and 'int main( int argc, char *argv[] )'  and optionally 'int main()'   The posted code uses none of these valid statements.  Suggest enabling all the warnings when compiling.  (for gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' )  Then the compiler will tell you about all the syntax errors.  Since the compiler knows the the language far better than us humans, fix the warnings

Comment: for readability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.   Note, for readability across different environments, never use tabs to indent

Answer (score 1):

You should also use a state variable which tells if you are currently inside a word or not.

Try:

```
state=OUT;
len=0;
max=-1;
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    if( (c==' '||c=='\n'||c=='\t') && state==IN)
    {
        state=OUT;
        l[len-1]++;
        if(l[len-1]>max)
                max=l[len-1];
        len=0;
    }
    else
    {
        state=IN;
        len++;
    }
}
```

PS: OUT and IN are symbolic constants which can have any but different values.
Also, you have to increment the element in array which matches the length (`l[len-1]++`).